# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\user.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Turn Off The Mobile Hotspot Of Your Computer**

If you're running into this problem, chances are high that your laptop's mobile hotspot is turned on. Switch off your hotspot and try rebuilding again. It works like magic.